# Using "if" and "case" to change hostname

Tags: linux, bash, sed, case, sh

I'm trying to use a "case" structure to provide options and "if" to actually perform the actions. I'm very very new in scripting so please forgive my lack of knowledge. To simplify things, I will skip any comments in the code and only use 1 (one) of the options for this script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo " 01. Select a new hostname"
read -p "Make your selection: " varSelection
 case $varSelection in
  1)
    read -p "$(echo -e 'Enter hostname here: \n')" varHostName
    read -p "¿Are u sure u want to use \" $varHostname \"? (y/n)"varHostNameRight
    if [ $varHostNameRight == y ]; then
        sed -i "s/^\(HOSTNAME\s*=\s*\).*\$/\1$varHostName/" /etc/sysconfig/network
        hostname $varHostName
    else
        if [ $varHostNameRight == n ]; then
    fi
    ;;
 esac
```

In this example, what I'd like to achive is that if user selects "y" in line "04", after executing lines 6 and 7 he returns to the "case" menu (as actually, there are more options in the case than 1)) I don't know how to do that :S after every option applies in my script, I have to re-run it to select other option.

Also, if user selects "no" in line "04", I would like to "loop" to line "03"...but again, I don't know how to do that :(

Please, any help is more than welcome!

Best regards,

Sebas

Comment: Please don't insert line numbers in your code. If you need to refer to a specific line, add a comment. And don't forget to format your code *as code* (highlight it and click the {} icon).

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! I'm sorry :S

Comment: So, one obvious problem is that you haven't actually written any possible matches for your `case` statement.  See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) for a nice example of `case` usage.

Comment: Hi dg99!Thanks for your comment! I must have missed copying it. The code works as expected until the "if [ $varHostNameRight == n ]; then" as i don't know how to tell the script to "jump" back to the line where it first asks 'Enter hostname here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop:

```
while read -p "Make your selection: " varSelection; do
...
done
```

and `break` appropriately.